# CakePHP has the wrong model name

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I'm trying out CakePHP now and I can't get my app working because CakePHP "thinks" my model name is 'Tach' when it's in fact 'Tache'.

Why so ?

My controller is defined as :
app/controllers/taches_controller.php

```
class TachesController extends AppController {

function index() {

    $allTaches = $this->Tache->find('all');

    $this->set('taches', $allTaches);

}
```

}

And here's my model :
app/models/tache.php

```
class Tache extends AppModel {

var $useTable = 'taches';
```

}

I get an error if I use 'Tache' in my controller :

```
        $allTaches = $this->Tache->find('all');
```

But if I use 'Tach', I get no error :

```
        $allTaches = $this->Tach->find('all');
```

Why can't I use the model name 'Tache' ? Am I doing something wrong ?  By the way I'm on php 5.3 and my CakePHP version is 1.3.8

Thanks !

Alex

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot. It's 1.3.8.

Comment: It looks like your Taches fell victim of some kind of automatic depluralization. Though I don't know CakePHP..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

CakePHP's default inflection rules think that Taches is the plural form of Tach.

You'll need to use the Inflector class to add a custom inflection.

See the following:

- Section [3.4.6 Inflections](http://book.cakephp.org/view/953/Inflections) of the cookbook. Which explains about custom inflections.
- [Inflector Class Info](http://api.cakephp.org/class/inflector) from the API doc.

To recap you'll need to add something like the following to your app/config/bootstrap.php file:

```
Inflector::rules('plural', array('irregular' => array('tache' => 'taches')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set $uses with the model name in the TachesController:

```
class TachesController extends AppController {

    var $uses = 'Tache';
```